# R: doParallel foreach with several data frames outputs

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a function that needs to manipulate three data frames, all with different structure:

- `a`: Original data frame. It is a parameter for my function. I need to remove rows from here, given certain conditions.
- `b`: New data frame created in my function. My function adds all the rows here.
- `c`: Another new data frame created in my function. My function adds all the rows here.

In order to try the parallel processing, I sat up a minimal code (following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318139/run-a-for-loop-in-parallel-in-r) and [this blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-r-loops-for-windows-and-linux/)) in which I only generated `b`:

```
# Set up the parallel
registerDoParallel( makeCluster(3L) )

b <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(f), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  tempB <- do_something_function()

  tempB
}
```

That example works perfectly, but I'm missing two data frames. I found other answers, but I do believe my case is different:

- [Saving multiple outputs of foreach dopar loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791609/saving-multiple-outputs-of-foreach-dopar-loop) -> As far as I understand, this is working with lists and not with data frames. Plus, all the results are "new" data frames, when I need to successively subset an existing data frame.
- [Output list of two rbinded data frames with foreach in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279164/output-list-of-two-rbinded-data-frames-with-foreach-in-r) -> This one says that all data frames must have the same structure. Mine do not.

I could change `a` to be a data frame of rows that would later be removed, but I need to merge all `tempA` with only `tempA`... if that makes any sense. In the previous questions I linked, they mix all of the outputs.

Comment: Can you give us a more reproducible example? (where your 3 dfs appear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem has nothing to do with parallelism, but rather about combining the results.

An example of solution of how I would do it (which I think is the most efficient way to do it):

```
library(foreach)
tmp <- foreach(i = seq_len(32)) %do% {
  list(iris[i, ], mtcars[i, ], iris[i, ])
}

lapply(purrr::transpose(tmp), function(l) do.call(rbind, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution so far. Instead of removing from `a`, I'm creating a data frame that is the rows that will be deleted. I wrote a combine function:

```
combine <- function(x, ...) {  
  mapply(rbind, x, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}
```

And my loop is something like this:

```
# Set up the parallel
registerDoParallel( makeCluster(3L) )

# Loop
output <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(f), .combine = combine, .multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {
  tempA <- get_this_value()
  tempB <- do_something_function()
  tempC <- get_this_other_frame()

  # Return the values
  list(tempA, tempB, tempC)
}
```

Then, I access the data using `output[[1]]` and so on. However, for this solution I'll still have to do a `setdiff` or `anti_join` after the loop, to remove the "undesired" rows from `a`.